# How I can get the difference between two text files?

Tags: php

I have two text file. I want to compare this two text file and want to create new text file with difference of this 2 files

Old_file.txt Contents:-

```
XYZ,Desc,46,XYZ,1.6000,0
XYZ1,Desc,56,XYZ1,8.6000,0
XYZ2,Desc,66,XYZ2,10.6000,0
XYZ3,Desc,76,XYZ3,11.6000,0
```

new_file.txt Contents:-

```
XYZ,Desc,46,XYZ,1.6000,0
XYZ1,Desc,86,XYZ1,9.6000,0
XYZ2,Desc,66,XYZ2,10.6000,0
XYZ3,Desc,100,XYZ3,11.6000,0
```

Need file:- (new_file.txt - old_file.txt)

```
XYZ1,Desc,86,XYZ1,9.6000,0
XYZ3,Desc,100,XYZ3,11.6000,0
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What constitutes a "difference" - is it "a line in file 2 that doesn't match the same line in file 1"? What if a line is missing? Do you assume that "similar" lines always start with the same word up to the comma? Need more information to help...

Comment: Have you even tried to do this yourself? If so, please list some code. If not, you are on the wrong site. StackOverflow isn't a place to get people to write code for you.

Comment: need missing line also with deleted flag and the end like XYZ5,Desc,100,XYZ3,11.6000,0,deleted                                       and similar lines always starts with same word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are coping what is usually refered as "[longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)", there are a looot of implementations of the most common algorithm. You can spot the solution of your problem working on the script provided [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff) pear package which is pretty robust. There's also the [xdiff](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php) extension, which you can do this with, using the [`xdiff_file_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php) function

```
xdiff_file_diff('Old_file.txt', 'new_file.txt', 'diff.txt');
```

Where diff.txt would be the resulting file with the comparison between the two files.